# cant save comma using update_option in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress 4.3 and in wp admin page i am saving admin email address using update_option.all works fine if i add single email.if i add comma separated email ids,the comma only missing in option.(var_dump($_request)) gives me the value with comma.only update_option function is omitting this value.is there any alternate option to store multiple emails separated by comma?

if i save admin@gmail.com,ragubathi@gmail.com the result will saves only admin@gmail.comragubathi@gmail.com which is incorrect.

```
 if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    var_dump($_REQUEST['admin_email']);
    if (current_user_can('edit_themes')) {
      update_option('admin_email', $_REQUEST['admin_email']);
 }
}
```

Comment: Show the `var_dump` result.!

Comment: @hemnath mouli here the var_dump result string(35) "admin@some.co.uk,ragubathi@gmail.com"

Comment: No you can't save multiple admin emails through simple way as WordPress doesn't support multiple admin emails...You will be needing to do it manually by saving it directly to Database table where admin emails are saved..!

Comment: Did you check the size of column in which you are updating the result, it might be the problem with the varchar size

Comment: Reference URL (You can't add multiple emails by simply adding them through your post request) : https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/is-it-possible-to-add-multiple-admin-email-addresses?hpv=b&utm_expid=3606929-74.aeX0WyvtRVa7qMe8Ph5smw.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.pk%2F#

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai thanks for reply.we can save one admin email with this code,my problem is need to add comma between those emails by code not by manual methods since it can be edited by the registered user.

Comment: How come a registered user can edit an admin email if you haven't given access to him/her to edit it???

Comment: @Ragubathi : Yes you can add comma to add multiple emails but you will be needing to do it through database by using  [**$wpdb (Class)**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: if a user is an administrator, he can edit this.(in my site i gave all access to change email,mobile number address etc... and ur link redirect to https://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-email-notifications-multiple-addresses which people says that its possible by using plugin or manual method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply like this way as :

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT admin_email FROM wp_options");
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
$admin_email = $results[0];
//Adding the new admin emails through POST Request
$update_admin_email = $_POST['update_admin_email'];

$wpdb->update( 
'wp_options', 
array( 
    'admin_email' => "$admin_email,$update_admin_email"
));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do an alternative way like this

```
 $arr = array(
     'email1',
     'email2',
     'email3',
 )
```

then serialize this array in using function php serialize

```
$dataToInsert = serialize($arr);
```

then update **$dataToInsert** variable in table,and you want to use that value in you code then retrieve this value from the table and use php function **unserialize**

```
$dataFromTable = unserialize($date); 
print_r($dataFromTable);
```